# Asserting a Flow type error in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, flowtype, assertion

We use [Flow](https://flow.org/) for static type-checking in JavaScript. Flow types can get complex, and we've had issues where we thought we had good static type guards against malformed objects, but Flow annotation issues meant that type checking didn't actually catch problems.

To prevent this problem, I'd like to write type-based "unit tests" that can statically assert our assumptions about type protections. This is easy if I want to assert the "valid" case, using [type assertions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/#toc-type-checking-through-type-assertions):

```
type User = {|
    name: string
|};

const user = {name: "Bob"};
(user: User);
```

This will pass if `user` is a valid `User`, and fail type check if it's not.

However, in order to assert the actual protections type checking gives us, I need to be able to assert Flow *errors*. For example, let's say I wanted to make sure this wasn't valid:

```
const user = {name: "Bob", age: 40};
```

I can make the test pass with

```
// $ExpectError
const user = {name: "Bob", age: 40};
```

but I can't make it fail with

```
// $ExpectError
const user = {name: "Bob"};
```

Obviously this example is pretty trivial, but more complex types (e.g. with generics) could benefit from this type of testing.

Options I've considered:

- I could potentially run `flow` as an external process on specific files and then assert that it returned an error, but this would require one file per test case
- I could use [flow-runtime](https://codemix.github.io/flow-runtime) to access the types at runtime and use them in unit tests, but this doesn't offer static assertions

**Is there any way to statically assert that a Flow assertion should fail, and throw an error if it doesn't?**

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) Flow is supposed to warn if a there is no error suppressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assert that certain lines of code in your unit tests should raise Flow errors, just write a Flow error suppression comment above those lines, then run `flow check --max-warnings 0` on your entire unit tests folder (or your entire codebase) and assert that the command has a 0 exit status (no errors or warnings). You don’t need to run the commands on each unit test file individually.

As the [documentation for `suppress_comment`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) says, Flow will raise a warning if you write a suppression comment such as `// $FlowExpectError` above a line that does not actually trigger a Flow error.

Assuming you defined your `suppress_comment` to understand `$FlowExpectError` as a suppression comment, this is what your unit tests would look like:

```js
// this type definition could be imported from another file
type User = {|
    name: string
|};

// Check that Flow doesn’t raise an error for correct usages
const user = {name: "Bob"};

// Check that Flow does raise an error for incorrect usages
// $FlowExpectError
const user = {name: "Bob", age: 40};
```

If you run `flow check --max-warnings 0` on a folder containing this file and the command exits successfully, then your tests for your `User` type passed.

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it doesn’t actually work in the current version of Flow. Unused type suppression is a warning, not an error, and while Flow displays the warning it exits with 0.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I have edited my answer to solve that problem. Flow has a built-in flag `--max-warnings` to change the exit status if there are warnings. I forgot it was necessary because the project I usually work on has it enabled by default.